# Split data between empty row

Tags: shell

```
===================================
dell1-node1.lvs.local

Device: t10.ATA_____DENCSTE251M252D0115______________________A09AY011202000268000000
VSANUUID: 5229819d-8308-e6a3-fea1-0716a6432ecd
SSD: True
Capacity: 79830188032
CapacityUsed: 0
DiskHealh: OK

Device: t10.ATA_____ST1000VX0012D1HH162__________________________________S513WZVV
VSANUUID: 526b1573-6e2e-111e-9748-a67d18a0093f
SSD: False
Capacity: 990191288320
CapacityUsed: 526032830464
DiskHealh: OK

===================================
dell1-node4.lvs.local

Device: t10.ATA_____ST2000VX0032D1HH164__________________________________W7208JYX
VSANUUID: 52219120-9951-3037-a871-11571eccf50e
SSD: False
Capacity: 1980382576640
CapacityUsed: 1337030868992
DiskHealh: OK

Device: t10.ATA_____DENCSTE251M252D0115______________________A09AY011210000027000000
VSANUUID: 52252706-4dcb-c73c-19f5-67719c29d0f6
SSD: True
Capacity: 79830188032
CapacityUsed: 0
DiskHealh: OK

===================================
dell1-node3.lvs.local

Device: naa.5000c5008c23ab53
VSANUUID: 5213b511-11b8-5f64-cb03-5a2d6ad258fa
SSD: False
Capacity: 990191288320
CapacityUsed: 682308403200
DiskHealh: OK

Device: naa.5000c5008c23ac7a
VSANUUID: 5236dc9a-b087-c2d8-2d24-2433218f3352
SSD: False
Capacity: 990191288320
CapacityUsed: 652595953664
DiskHealh: OK

Device: naa.5e83a97010008946
VSANUUID: 52f99ae4-970c-7369-de9d-7b93f0d9b5df
SSD: True
Capacity: 79830188032
CapacityUsed: 0
DiskHealh: OK
```

Hi all, I need to copy this string to a file: 
`dell1-node4.lvs.local`

```
Device: t10.ATA_____ST2000VX0032D1HH164__________________________________W7208JYX
VSANUUID: 52219120-9951-3037-a871-11571eccf50e
SSD: False
Capacity: 1980382576640
CapacityUsed: 1337030868992
DiskHealh: OK

Device: t10.ATA_____DENCSTE251M252D0115______________________A09AY011210000027000000
VSANUUID: 52252706-4dcb-c73c-19f5-67719c29d0f6
SSD: True
Capacity: 79830188032
CapacityUsed: 0
DiskHealh: OK
```

And then continue copy this string to another file:

```
t10.ATA_____DENCSTE251M252D0115______________________A09AY011210000027000000
VSANUUID: 52252706-4dcb-c73c-19f5-67719c29d0f6
SSD: True
Capacity: 79830188032
CapacityUsed: 0
DiskHealh: OK
```

Comment: Could you please be more clear?

Comment: Yep, I need to grep string between "==================================="

Comment: @AshishK not really, you should pay attention on [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @C0dekid I didn't get you. Actually I just thought of editing this question after confirming from trungtien that only the lines between "====" had to be extracted to the mentioned file

Answer (score 0):

If you want all the contents between "====" to be stored in the given file, this will work. I have tested it on my system as well. Good luck!

```
awk '/dell/{flag=1;next}/=/{flag=0}flag' <filename> > dell1-node4.lvs.local
```

- `/dell/` matches lines having this text, as well as `/=/` does.
- `/dell/{flag=1;next}` sets the flag when the text `dell` is found.
  Then, it skips the line.
- `/=/{flag=0}` unsets the flag when the text `=` is found.
- The final flag is a pattern with the default action, which is to
  print `$0:` if flag is equal 1 the line is printed.